# Nullpointer exception when inflating a ListView in a library project

Tags: android

Currently I'm developing a library for my own usage. My class in this library is called `BaseWindow`, my library project has included the `SlidingMenu` project as a library as well. I get a `NullPointerException` when I try to get a `listView` from my layout folder. My class is constructed like this:

```
public class BaseWindow extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

    private String windowTitle; 
    private int menuResourceId;

    /**
     * @param layoutResourceId identificator of the layout to inflate(R.layout.your_layout)
     * @param menuResourceId identification of the menu to inflate(R.layout.your_menu)
     * @param windowTitle title of this window
     */
    public void InitializeWindow(int layoutResourceId, int menuResourceId, String windowTitle)  {

     ...........
     ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.menu_listview); 

    }   

}
```

I know that stuff like this should be done in a `onCreate` method. But is it possible to do so outside, like I do? When I'm holding my mousepointer over the `findViewById` method, it does actually reference the method in my superclass

```
View com.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.findViewById(int id)
```

the `SlidingFragmentActivity` class extends the   `SherlockFragmentActivity`

Does anybody know what causes the problem? My is my `lv` object. null? how can I get my ListView correct from this library class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should inflate an xml that contains `menu_listview` first:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xml_containing_listview);

ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);
```

This is only concept, I didn't test this so it may not work. Also you need to have a context.

Answer (score 1):

The `setContentView()` method of `onCreate` in `activity` is important as because it is used to inflate the layout and collect its view and resources in object. But while creating a separate class and using ids directly will not inflate your layout so there are 3 ways to do so

1) Pass the list view directly to the method of non activity method

2) Inflate layout

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View externalView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_containing_listview);
ListView listView = (ListView) externalView .findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);
```

3) Directly inflate layout and use it

```
LayoutInflater mInflater= (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View externalView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_containing_listview, null);
 ListView listView = (ListView) externalView .findViewById(R.id.menu_listview);
```

Choose which is best suited for your code

Answer (score 0):

Could be several reasons:

1. `InitializeWindow()` is being called before `setContentView()`, Activity doesn't has a layout yet.
2. Id `menu_listview` does not exists in `R.layout.***` layout inflated by Activity.
3. You are referring `R` from wrong package (App vs Library).